# Defining relationship between sql server and mysql in laravel 5.2

Tags: mysql, sql-server, eloquent, laravel-5, relationships

I have two database connections one is **sql server** and other is a **mysql**. Now, I have a model named `Film`

```
<?php
namespace App\EloquentModels;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Film extends Model {

    /**
     * Db server to use
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $connection = 'sqlsrv';

    /**
     * Database table name
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'SYN_tblFilm';

//relationship defined between film and film details.
public function filmDetail()
{
        return $this->hasOne('App\EloquentModels\FilmDetail');
}
```

Now the `Film` model uses the **sql server** connection and if I find the first entry from the model just to show you guys what it returns,

it returns this when I do `App\EloquentModels\Film::first();`

```
App\EloquentModels\Film Object
(
    [connection:protected] => sqlsrv
    [table:protected] => SYN_tblFilm
    [primaryKey:protected] => id
    [keyType:protected] => int
    [perPage:protected] => 15
    [incrementing] => 1
    [timestamps] => 1
    [attributes:protected] => Array
        (
            [Film_strCode] => 0001HO00002378   //this is  unique identifier 
            [Film_strTitle] => EVERLY(A)-ENG
            [Film_strCensor] => R16
            [Film_strContent] => Joe Lynch

            [Film_strDescription] => Salma Hayek, Hiroyuki Watanabe, Laura Cepeda
            [Film_strShortName] => EVERLY(A)
            [Film_strSignText] => EVERLY(A)-ENG
            [Film_bytSignSequence] => 50
            [FilmCat_strCode] => 
            [FilmCat_strName] => 
            [FilmCat_strShortName] => 
            [Film_strChildren] => N
            [Film_intDuration] => 92
            [Film_strStatus] => A
            [Film_strATMAvailable] => Y
            [Film_strShortCode] => EVERLY(A)
            [Film_intIVRCode] => 0
            [Film_strURL1] => 
            [Film_strURL2] => 
            [Film_strVCode] => 
            [Film_strTitleAlt] => 
            [Film_strCensorAlt] => 
            [Film_strContentAlt] => 
            [Film_strDescriptionAlt] => 
            [Film_strShortNameAlt] => 
            [Film_strSignTextAlt] => 
            [Film_strURL1Description] => 
            [Film_strURL2Description] => 
            [Film_strURLforGraphic] => 
            [Film_strURLforFilmName] => 
            [Film_strURLforTrailer] => 
            [Film_strMovieFormat] => 
            [Film_strSoundFormat] => 
            [Film_mnyGross] => 0.0000
            [Film_mnyLocalGross] => 0.0000
            [Film_strUpcomingFlag] => Y
            [Film_strFeatureFlag] => N
            [Film_strNowShowingFlag] => N
            [Film_dtmOpeningDate] => 2016-07-27 04:15:57.000
            [Film_strDescriptionLong] => Salma Hayek, Hiroyuki Watanabe, Laura Cepeda

            [Film_strAdditionalData] => 
            [Film_dtmStamp] => 2016-07-27 04:24:13.953
        )

    [original:protected] => Array
        (
            [Film_strCode] => 0001HO00002378
            [Film_strTitle] => EVERLY(A)-ENG
            [Film_strCensor] => R16
            [Film_strContent] => Joe Lynch

            [Film_strDescription] => Salma Hayek, Hiroyuki Watanabe, Laura Cepeda
            [Film_strShortName] => EVERLY(A)
            [Film_strSignText] => EVERLY(A)-ENG
            [Film_bytSignSequence] => 50
            [FilmCat_strCode] => 
            [FilmCat_strName] => 
            [FilmCat_strShortName] => 
            [Film_strChildren] => N
            [Film_intDuration] => 92
            [Film_strStatus] => A
            [Film_strATMAvailable] => Y
            [Film_strShortCode] => EVERLY(A)
            [Film_intIVRCode] => 0
            [Film_strURL1] => 
            [Film_strURL2] => 
            [Film_strVCode] => 
            [Film_strTitleAlt] => 
            [Film_strCensorAlt] => 
            [Film_strContentAlt] => 
            [Film_strDescriptionAlt] => 
            [Film_strShortNameAlt] => 
            [Film_strSignTextAlt] => 
            [Film_strURL1Description] => 
            [Film_strURL2Description] => 
            [Film_strURLforGraphic] => 
            [Film_strURLforFilmName] => 
            [Film_strURLforTrailer] => 
            [Film_strMovieFormat] => 
            [Film_strSoundFormat] => 
            [Film_mnyGross] => 0.0000
            [Film_mnyLocalGross] => 0.0000
            [Film_strUpcomingFlag] => Y
            [Film_strFeatureFlag] => N
            [Film_strNowShowingFlag] => N
            [Film_dtmOpeningDate] => 2016-07-27 04:15:57.000
            [Film_strDescriptionLong] => Salma Hayek, Hiroyuki Watanabe, Laura Cepeda

            [Film_strAdditionalData] => 
            [Film_dtmStamp] => 2016-07-27 04:24:13.953
        )

    [relations:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [hidden:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [visible:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [appends:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [fillable:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [guarded:protected] => Array
        (
            [0] => *
        )

    [dates:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [dateFormat:protected] => 
    [casts:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [touches:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [observables:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [with:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [morphClass:protected] => 
    [exists] => 1
    [wasRecentlyCreated] => 
)
```

Now in this model the unique identifier would be `[Film_strCode] => 0001HO00002378` which is a string i.e `Film_strCode VarChar (20) Film Code`. Probably unique for all sites.

Now I have another model named `filmDetail` which uses a **mysql** connection

The schema for the `film detail` would be -:

```
 Schema::create('film_details', function (Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->increments('id'); 
            $table->string('Film_strCode', 255);  //here we are saving the Film_strCode which is unique identifier in Film model
            $table->text('summary')->default(null)->nullable();
            $table->string('director_cast', 255)->default(null)->nullable();
            $table->string('writer_cast', 255)->default(null)->nullable();
            $table->string('star_cast', 255)->default(null)->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Now I want to define a relationship between `Film` and `FilmDetail` model so that I could fetch the film details from the film like this

```
$filmDetail = Film::find(1)->filmDetail();
```

This is how I have defined the relationship between the `Film` and `filmDetail`

```
//I have written this is the Film model
public function filmDetail()
{
        return $this->hasOne('App\EloquentModels\FilmDetail');
}
```

Please assist how will I fetch `filmDetails` from the `Film` Model ?

Answer (score 0):

Change relationship method as given below, in your film Model:

```
public function filmDetail()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\EloquentModels\FilmDetail','Film_strCode','Film_strCode');
}
```

Now, to fetch film details, use

```
$filmDetail = Film::find(1)->filmDetail();
```

Comment: which key relates the filmDetails table to films ?

Comment: Film_strCode in film table

Comment: @AdityaBanerjee are you getting any error ? or just a null value ?